# asp.net upload files between projects in solution

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, project, solution

My solution is divided into few pieces like database part logic part wcfs that comunicate between portal and logic

I have a AdminPortal and UserPortal project when admin uploads a file like pdf or doc it lands in a folder on AdminPortal. UserPortal have no access to that part so how can i make them this files visible for them???

Help will be appriciated. Sorry for my crappy english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem using settings DB table and value administrationHost + fileUploadLocation + fileName

Used in Hyperlink downloads between to portals just fine

Answer (score 0):

2 options: 1. save the files into db. 2. create a virtual folder shared by both apps in iis